# Cannot convert typename from int to std::string despite testing it is a std::string using std::is_same

Tags: c++

This is my first time using templates so I suspect I'm using it incorrectly.

Several times in my code I get a list of space-delimited values per line from the console. Sometimes I wanted the list to be a pair of `std::strings` or one `std::string` and one `int` - you get the point. So I wanted to create a type-ambiguous function that could handle all at once just by referencing the list.

---

The following worked fine:

```
template<typename A, typename B> void getInputList(std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> &list) {
    //redacted while loop
    A a;
    B b;
    if ((ss >> a >> b) && ss.eof())
        list.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
    else {
        std::cout << "Bad values ignored" << ((list.size() != 0) ? ", previous values still in buffer.\n" : ".\n");
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

However if the types were `std::string` and `int` and I input:

> 56 56

The code would accept it and I want strings to solely be alphas. So then I added a test to see if either of the inputs was a `std::string`, and if so, make sure it doesn't have a number:

```
 template<typename A, typename B> void getInputList(std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> &list) {
    //redacted while loop
    A a;
    B b;
    if ((ss >> a >> b) && ss.eof()) {
        if (std::is_same<A, std::string>::value)
            if(std::all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), ::isdigit))
                continue;
        if (std::is_same<B, std::string>::value) 
            if(std::all_of(b.begin(), b.end(), ::isdigit))
                continue;
        list.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
        continue;
    }
    //more redacted code
}
```

This gives the following errors but **only** for `b`, `a` doesn't throw any errors:

> left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
>   left of '.end' must have class/struct/union

---

I created a temporary function to see why, and while `a` has type `A`, `b` has type `int`.

```
bool isString(std::string in) {
    return std::all_of(in.begin(), in.end(), ::isdigit);
}
template<typename A, typename B> void getInputList(std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> &list) {
//redacted while loop
    A a;
    B b;
    if ((ss >> a >> b) && ss.eof()) {
       if (std::is_same<A, std::string>::value)
          if(isString(a))
            continue;
       if (std::is_same<B, std::string>::value) 
          if(isString(b))
            continue;
       list.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
       continue;
   }
   //more redacted code
}
```

Which gives:

> cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::string'

If I apply `std::to_string` to both then `a` creates an error:

> 'std::to_string': none of the 9 overloads could convert all the argument types

Because it is of type `A` as it should be...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most circumstances, all of the statements in a function template specialization must be valid, even if they can never be executed.

If you can use C++17, it introduced "`if constexpr`" to solve this issue: when you type `if constexpr` instead of just `if`, it must be possible to evaluate the condition at compile time, and any controlled statement which cannot possibly be executed for a given set of template arguments is not instantiated with those template arguments at all.

If you can't use C++17, you could dispatch to a helper function to do your validations.  The key is to call a different function depending on whether the type is a `std::string` or something else.

```
// A string must not be all digits:
inline bool validateInput(const std::string& s) {
    return !std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isdigit);
}
// Any other type is always valid:
template <typename T>
bool validateInput(const T&) { return true; }

template<typename A, typename B>
void getInputList(std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> &list) {
    // ...
    while (something()) {
        A a;
        B b;
        if ((ss >> a >> b) && ss.eof()) {
            if (!validateInput(a)) continue;
            if (!validateInput(b)) continue;
            list.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
            continue;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, had never heard of `if constexpr` looks perfect for this, how would I use that instead or would you just use template specialisation anyway? The answer you already provided solved the problem

Comment: @jaunt If you're using a recent enough version of clang or gcc, you can pass "-std=c++1z" as a command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your type check (`std::is_same<A, std::string>::value`) is a runtime test.
so the compiler dosn't know if it will be true or not, and goes on.
Then you call a function with `std::string` argument with your templated type variables. This results in a type error when your template is `int` (or anything else).

To solve this I recommend you to use template specialization:

```
// base template, used if no specialization matches
template<typename T>
bool stringContainingDigits(T in) {
  // no string
  return false;
}

// string specialization only used if string
template<>
bool stringContainingDigits<std::string>(std::string in) {
  // true if only contains digits
  return std::all_of(in.begin(), in.end(), ::isdigit);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
void getInputList(std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> &list) {
  //redacted while loop
  A a;
  B b;
  if ((ss >> a >> b) /* && ss.eof() */) {
    if(stringContainingDigits(a))
      continue;
    if(stringContainingDigits(b))
      continue;
    list.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
    continue
  }
  //more redacted code
}
```

BTW if you have your `if` statement within a loop where to continue to read form the same stream `ss`, you might rather omit the EOF test, because it would be only true for the very last item.

Comment: Ah thank you for that re `eof`. I still find it strange that only one of them failed though